# Postgresql loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this data.

| customer_id | start_date | last_date | difference_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/12/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 4 |

And my goal is to make this table look like the one below.

| customer_id | payment_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/12/2022 |
| 1 | 09/12/2022 |
| 1 | 10/12/2022 |
| 1 | 11/12/2022 |
| 1 | 12/12/2022 |

I'm using PostgreSQL, and I feel like it's a pretty easy thing to do using loop but I have never used loop in SQL. I did try but couldn't make it work. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate the number of months and then add that to the start_date

```
select t.customer_id, 
       (t.start_date + make_interval(months => g.num))::date as payment_date
from the_table t
   cross join generate_series(0, t.difference_month) as g(num)
order by payment_date
```